# Show that the set $z$ satisfying $|z-z_0|=\rho|z-z_1|$ ($\rho \neq 1$) is a circle.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Prove that for $\rho \ge 0$, $\rho \neq 1$ and fix $z_0,z_1 \in \Bbb C$. Show that the set $z \in \Bbb C$ satisfying $|z-z_0|=\rho|z-z_1|$ is a circle.

From the given condition I have reached that $(1-\rho^2)|z|^2 -2\mathfrak{Re} (\bar z (z_0-\rho^2 z_1)) + |z_0|^2 -\rho^2|z_1|^2=0$
But I do not get my desired result.

Comment: Why don't you tackle it geometrically? Draw a line from $z_0$ to $z_1$, draw the points on this line satisfying the equation (there must be two), then find the centre point between these two, the equation of that circle, and show all points satisfy the equation?

Comment: Then I have to show that no other point satisfy that eqn. Will you do it elaborately and give me the answer? Because I think doing algebraic way will be shorter.

Comment: Have you already treated Möbius transformations?

Comment: No, I have not used it. This is first chapter problem in Gamelin's book and I want to do it in an elementary way.

Comment: Okay, then do it per pedes. So you found that the condition is equivalent to $a\lvert z\rvert^2 - 2 \operatorname{Re}(b\overline{z}) + c = 0$ for some real $a,c$ with $a \neq 0$ and $b \in \mathbb{C}$. When is that sort of equation the defining equation for a circle?

Comment: Oh yes this will be eqn of a circle if $(b/a)^2 - c/a$ is a positive term.

Comment: Sorry $|b/a|^2 - c/a$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From where you left off

$$(1-\rho^{2})|z|^{2}-\lbrace z^{*}(z_{0}-\rho^{2}z_{1})+z(z_{0}-\rho^{2}z_{1})^{*}\rbrace=\rho^{2}|z_{1}|^{2}-|z_{0}|^{2}$$

Dividing by $(1-\rho^{2})$ and completing the square

$$|z-\frac{1}{(1-\rho^{2})}(z_{0}-\rho^{2}z_{1})|^{2}=\frac{\rho^{2}|z_{1}|^{2}-|z_{0}|^{2}}{1-\rho^{2}}+|\frac{1}{(1-\rho^{2})}(z_{0}-\rho^{2}z_{1})|^{2} $$

Comment: we have a winner.

Comment: And you have to show that the RHS is non negative and it is true if $z_0 \neq z_1$

Comment: How exactly is the square completed? How do you arrive at the term $|\frac{1}{1-\rho^2}(z_0 - \rho^2 z_1)|^2$?

Answer (score 1):

WOLOG, we may assume $z_1 =0$. Then we are looking at $|z-z_0|=\rho |z|$. Next, by rotation, we may assume that $a=z_0$ is real and positive.

Now, let $z=x+iy$ and square the equation to get
$(x-a)^2 +y^2=\rho^2 (x^2 +y^2)$. When this is expanded, a conic section is obtained with equal coefficients for $x$ and $y$. This is a circle.

Alternatively, and using what you wrote, let $z=x+iy$ and find that the coefficients of $x^2$ and $y^2$ are the same, and there is $xy$ term. This gives a circle.

Answer (score 0):

Hint..you can write $z=x+iy$, $z_0=a+ib$, $z_1=c+id$ for real $x,y,a,b,c,d$ and apply your condition so that you get$$(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=\rho^2[(x-c)^2+(y-d)^2]$$ which will lead to the equation of a circle

Comment: Is this a hint?? When I have done that calculation then there is no point saying me to put $z,z_0$ etc etc.

Comment: I think there should be an $x - c$ on the RHS instead of $-c$. Otherwise this seems like the most elegant, concise solution.

Comment: @ColmBhandal: yes! Thanks

Comment: @user152715 it is only intended as a hint in the sense that this will lead to the solution but does not constitute the full solution

Comment: @DavidQuinn which are the radius and the center of the circle?

Answer (score 0):

Begin by noting that $\langle x+iy,a+ib \rangle = xa+yb = \text{Re}\left((x+iy)(a-ib)\right)$ so if we think of $z$ and $w$ as two-dimensional vectors then the complex algebra permits a natural formulation of the Euclidean inner-product in the plane:
$$ \langle v,w \rangle  = \text{Re} (v \bar{w}) $$
On the other hand, we have $|z|^2 = z \bar{z}$ and the many wonderful properties of the complex conjugate. Suppose $|z-z_o| = \rho|z-z_1|$ for some $\rho>0$ (if I say $\rho>0$ then it must be real !). Square the given condition and use properties of complex conjugation:
$$ (z-z_o)(\bar{z}-\bar{z_o}) = \rho^2(z-z_1)(\bar{z}-\bar{z_1})$$
or
$$ z\bar{z}-z\bar{z_o}-z_o\bar{z}+z_o\bar{z_o} = \rho^2\left( z\bar{z}-z\bar{z_1}-z_1\bar{z}+z_1\bar{z_1}\right)$$
which gives
$$ |z|^2-z\bar{z_o}-z_o\bar{z}+|z_o|^2 = \rho^2\left( |z|^2-z\bar{z_1}-z_1\bar{z}+|z_1|^2\right)$$
which we can rearrange to
$$ \rho^2z\bar{z_1}+\rho^2z_1\bar{z}-z\bar{z_o}-z_o\bar{z} = 
(\rho^2-1)|z|^2 +\rho^2|z_1|^2- |z_o|^2$$
Ok, I'm tired of $\rho$, I'm setting $\rho=1$ in which case:
$$ z\bar{z_1}+z_1\bar{z}-z\bar{z_o}-z_o\bar{z} = 
|z_1|^2- |z_o|^2$$
which gives, using $\text{Re}(z) = \frac{1}{2}(z + \bar{z})$,
$$ z(\overline{z_1-z_o})+\bar{z}(z_1-z_o) = 2\text{Re}\left(z(\overline{z_1-z_o})\right) = |z_1|^2- |z_o|^2$$
or,
$$ \langle z, z_1-z_o \rangle = \frac{1}{2}\left(|z_1|^2- |z_o|^2\right) $$
Now, if we have $|z_o| = |z_1|$ then it follows:
$$ \langle z, z_1-z_o \rangle = 0 $$
which says $z$ points in a direction perpendicular to the line-segment from $z_0$ to $z_1$. In any event, you can use the things I've done here to find the answer.

Comment: ok, so while I have not answered the question I at least showed you why $\rho=1$ is not allowed.