# Completing the square with complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, completing-the-square

**Dear MSE-community!**

I have begun on a journey through Gamelin's *Complex Analysis*. In the first chapter is an exercise described in the Math.SE question ["Show that the set $z$ satisfying $|z−z_0|=\rho|z−z_1|\quad(\rho\neq 1)$ is a circle"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1385817/409).

The [accepted answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1385874/409) is making a completion of squares:

$$\begin{align}
|z|^2 - \frac{1}{1-\rho^2}\bar{z}(z_0 - \rho^2 z_1) + \frac{1}{1-\rho^2}z(\overline{z_0 - \rho^2 z_1}) 
&= \frac{\rho^2 |{z_1}|^2 - |{z_0}|^2}{1 - {\rho}^2} \tag{1}\\
\iff \qquad \left|z-\frac1{1-\rho^2}\left(z_0-\rho^2z_1
\right)\right|^2 &=\frac{\rho^2|z_1|^2-|z_0|^2}{1-\rho^2}+\left|\frac{1}{1-\rho^2}(z_0-\rho^2z_1)\right|^2 \tag{2}
\end{align}$$

I have myself derived equality $(1)$, but I cannot understand how to fill in the details myself regarding the completion of squares.

---

I am writing this as a question because I have no one to ask about it, and I have too low reputation to comment on the original thread.

All help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Expand the left-hand side of equation $(2)$ and compare it to equation $(1)$.  When you do that, you'll see what we mean by completing the square.  We just added to equation $(1)$ the exact term necessary to make its left-hand side a square.

Comment: How is the LHS of eq. (2) expanded? Rewriting in terms of real and imaginary part etc?

Comment: @iaenastrom $|z-w|^2=(z-w)(\overline{z-w})=|z|^2+|w|^2-z\overline{w}-\overline{z}w,$ where $w=\frac{1}{1-\rho^2}(z_0-\rho^2 z_1).$